# Transaction not successfully started in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm new to hibernate.
I want to use transaction in iterator, so i did like this:

```
Session session = opensession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
for {
    try {
        something = session.get;
        something.setX = X;
        session.save(something)
        tx.commit(); <-- error occurs after iterated once.
    catch { tx.rollback(); }
}
something2 = session.get;
something2.setX = X;
session.save(something2);
tx.commit():
session.close();
```

But hibernate occurs `Transaction not successfully started` error
What's wrong !?;

Comment: please provide pure code so that one can understand easily your problem

Comment: @NiravPrajapati That's all without business logic, i just want to commit the transaction before finishing each iteration.

Comment: You can't commit the same transactions multiple times. If a transaction is committed, then you need to start a new one.

Comment: @JBNizet So i injected code `transaction = session.beginTransaction` to begin with for statement, but the program often occurs `lock wait timeout exceeded`. Although i have configured `innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120` in mysql configuration and restarted mysql, same error was occured.